# Finding the IP address of a Cisco 3750G

Tags: cisco, switch, ip, cisco-3750

Hello i have a Cisco 3750G switch and i need to find the IP address and I dont have a serial cable, so I need the IP address to login into the web-interface. Does it need to be connected to a network? I have a big network 100+ users so IP scanning is not an option

Thanks

Comment: Do you even know if it has been configured with an IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check for LLDP or CDP advertisements on connected ports (proper tool or packet capturing) or adjacent devices - these usually include the (main) local IP address.
- Check the DHCP server for a current lease on the switch's MAC address (should be printed on the back).
- Run a quick ARP scan, the switch shows up with its MAC address.